# PHP Regular Expressions. Searching for double quotes?

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a PHP webpage that takes data from a search box and uses it to search a mysql database and return the results. Currently it just uses the mySQL LIKE query with all of the data provided. This is not very flexible as it treats the data as a single exact expression to match.

After a quick google I found this page ( http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/search/ ) which I plan to use to expand the functionality of my search webpage.

However I have two queries about the tutorial on that webpage:

1) The first section of the tutorial is this:

```
$terms = preg_replace("/\"(.*?)\"/e", "search_transform_term('\$1')", $terms);
```

I don't understand why the * is followed by a ?, as I understand it the .* means one character (can be any character) zero or more times which means any string. The ? means zero or one times. Therefore doesn't .*? also mean any string?

2) My second question is how would I cause the expression to replace expressions contained in speech marks instead of brackets?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in 2)

Comment: The preg_replace("/\"(.*?)\"/e", "search_transform_term('\$1')", $terms); function shown above is used to find all pairs of brackets and pass their contents to search_transform_term for further processing. I would like to find all pairs of speech marks and pass their contents to search_transform_term for futher processing.

Comment: It looks to me that it matches all pair of quotation marks, not brackets. I am not sure what speech marks is! :)

Comment: Speech marks are the same as quotation marks :) I also thought that it was searching for anything encased in quotation marks but thought I was mistaken because my knowledge of regex is extremely limited. Looks like it was just a mistake/misunderstanding in the wording of the tutorial :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer to 1.

**.*?** means, that operator **.*** is lazy. What does it means.

Every operator in regex is greedy, it try to find maximum, adding ? it becomes lazy, it try to find minimum.

When I use

```
preg_replace("/_(.*)_/","Hi,_first_ and _second_ element","!replaced!");
```

output will be

```
Hi,!replaced! element
```

Because it find maximum of text, but in this case:

```
preg_replace("/_(.*?)_/","Hi,_first_ and _second_ element","!replaced!");
```

output will be

```
Hi,!replaced! and !replaced! element
```

Because it try to find minimum of text which match the regexp.

I hope that this is enough, because I don't know how to explain it better :D

Answer (score 1):

The question mark makes the matching non greedy so that php tries to match as few characters as possible before it encounters a " char.

Comment: That makes sense because if the user specified multiple quotes, the .* would only find one quote because only the first and last brackets would be taken into account, any brackets in between would be seen as part of the quote. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

- The star(*) allows the dot to be repeated any number of times, including
  zero.
- The question mark(?) makes the preceding token in the regular
  expression optional. E.g.: colou?r matches both colour and color.